# STDOUT to multiple variables

Tags: bash, shell, variables, stdout, sh

I have a custom program that runs from a shell and downloads a file(s) and also outputs some info about the file(s) it downloads?

```
    sh-3.1$ superdl -l username -p password filename
    Logging in...
    OK
    File: "filename"
    Size: "1100 bytes"
    Type: "text"
    Encryption: "RSA"
    Encoding: "utf-8"
    Done!
```

Comment: You can `superdl | tee file` and then grep that file.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware about that. I want more elegant way ;)

Comment: `Yes, I'm aware about that. I want more elegant way ;)` -- You seem to say *do it for me*.

Comment: If `superdl` is a custom program, then do the following: write the current output to standard error instead, and write to output lines like `TYPE=text`. Then evaluate the output of the program with `eval "$(superdl ...)"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of doing it in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r var val
do
    [[ $var == Type: ]] && type="$val"
    [[ $var == Encryption: ]] && encryption="$val"
    [[ $var == Encoding: ]] && encoding="$val"
done < <(./superdl -l username -p password filename)

echo "$type $encryption $encoding"
```

Output:

```
text RSA utf-8
```

Or with a case statement:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r var val
do
    case "$var" in
    Type: )
        type="$val" ;;
    Encryption: )
        encryption="$val" ;;
    Encoding: )
         encoding="$val" ;;
    esac
done < <(./superdl -l username -p password filename)

echo "$type $encryption $encoding"
```

Regarding the Edit in the question, nothing really changes. You can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in "$@"
do

    while read -r var val
    do
        [[ $var == Type: ]] && type="$val"
        [[ $var == Encryption: ]] && encryption="$val"
        [[ $var == Encoding: ]] && encoding="$val"
    done < <(./superdl -l username -p password "$filename")

    echo "$type $encryption $encoding"
done
```

Comment: what if i want to pass multiple arguments in a script? like: superdl "$@"

Comment: @user2791506 You can just do that. What is the problem?

Comment: @user2791506 Nothing really changes in this case. Just put the while loop inside the for loop.

Comment: i mean is there more elegant way than doing this: < <(./superdl -l username -p password "$filename")

Comment: @user2791506 Can't think of a more elegant way of doing it right now. But using process substitution like this seems natural to me